# How can I use an external variable to define loop variable?

Tags: loops, ansible

I have a dictionary and I want to loop over specific one

```yaml
example1:   [
           { value1: "path", value2: "path2" },
        ]

example2:   [
           { value1: "path3", value2: "path4" },
        ]
```

**`playbook.yaml`**

```yaml
- name: echodict
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    choose_dict: example1

  roles:
   - /home/user/ansible/roles/dicttest
```

**`dicttest.yml`**

```yaml
- name: loopdict
  ansible.builtin.command: "echo {{ item }}"
  register: test
  loop:
    - "{{ choose_dict }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ test }}"
```

Is there a way to choose `example1` or `example2` via external variables?

Comment: It's not clear from your question exactly what you're trying to do. Can you edit the question to include a complete playbook that demonstrates your goal, and explain specifically where you're having difficulties?

Comment: done, hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you're asking. You can use the [`vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html) lookup to get the value of a variable whose name is stored in another variable. For example, given this playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    example1:
      - value: path1
      - value: path2
    example2:
      - value: path3
      - value: path4
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          path: "{{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('vars', choose_dict) }}"
```

We can run `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e choose_dict=example1` and get:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': 'path1'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "path": "path1"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': 'path2'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "path": "path2"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Or we can run `ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e choose_dict=example2` and get:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': 'path3'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "path": "path3"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': 'path4'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "path": "path4"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```